# Counter-intuitive result to an Integral calculus problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Consider the equations $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ in the first quadrant,

My hypothesis is that the solids produced by rotating the area enclosed by the equations about x axis and y axis will have the same volume.

But when i use integration methods to find the volume of those solids

For rotation about x-axis:-

$ V_1=\pi\int_{0}^{1}( x^2-x^4 )\,dx $

For rotation about y-axis:-

$ V_2=\pi\int_{0}^{1}( y-y^2)\,dy $

$Clearly,  V_1\neq V_2$

But this is very counter intuitive for me since both volumes can be understood as infinite sum of the same area about the two different axes.
Is there something that i am missing?

Thanks for your help

Edit:
When i sweep the area slice by a small constant angle about both axes ,i will endup with a larger arclength as a result of larger outer radius in case of the rotation with respect to $y axis$ compared to $x axis$ giving more volume for the same angle no matter the angle.
This extends my intuition to considering areas as sum of arclengths,which i need to consider more.

Comment: The solid that comes about from rotating around the $y$ axis will be larger because the "meatier" part of the crescent gets rotated through a wider a circle than if you were rotating about the $x$ axis, because the shape in general is "further away" from the $y$ axis than the $x$ axis.

Comment: Hmmm, but if i consider rotating the area element about x axis with a small angle d(theta) and i do the same with the y axis, do you think we will get the same result?

Comment: No, there is no reason to think so. As an extreme case, take a rectangle $[0,2]\times[0,1]$. If you rotate it both ways, which one has the larger volume? Do they still have the same cross sectional area even though their volumes are different?

Comment: Both will give rise to cylinders with different volumes but same cross sectional area. Hmmm , but does this hold for small rotations as well ? I mean they will approximately have the same value but do they still have a difference?

Comment: You're forgetting that the small infinitesimal rotation length element is given by $rd\theta$, not just $d\theta$. The one with the larger arc length (which means larger radius) would have the larger volume slice.

Comment: Please don't use a differential geometry tag if you don't know what it's for.

Comment: @Planck this may be of interest to you too (esp. the second theorem)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem#:~:text=Goodman%20%26%20Goodman%20generalize%20the%20second,solid%20does%20not%20intersect%20itself.)

Comment: @Math Lover thanks !! What prerequisites do i need for understanding its proof in for n-dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating about the $y$ would be the same thing as using the shells method on $x$. Compare the two integrals

$$\pi\int_0^1 f_1^2(x)-f_2^2(x)dx$$

$$2\pi\int_0^1x(f_1(x)-f_2(x))dx$$

Assuming $f_1>f_2$ on $(0,1)$ et's see when the integrands are equivalent

$$\pi(f_1^2(x)-f_2^2(x)) = 2\pi x(f_1(x)-f_2(x)) \implies f_1(x)+f_2(x) = 2x$$

so if the sum of the functions is less than $2x$, than rotation about the $y$ will be larger.

Comment: I still have to look into shells method, thanks for letting me know of it's existence.